# Is there away to return a query for test cases with the starting letter of a string from a tag

Tags: tfs, testcase

I am trying to fetch test cases from tfs from `Field item = tag | operator = does not contain | value = starts with`.

For instance.
My tags are `test_1, test_2, test_3 ... etc`.
I wanted to run a query that returns test cases that does not contain `test_1,test_2,test_3....` 
instead of running

```
Field item = tag | operator = does not contain  | value= "test_1" 
                   Field item = tag | operator = does not contain  | value= "test_2" 
                   Field item = tag | operator = does not contain  | value= "test_3"... etc
```

can I run something similar to `Field item = tag | operator =  does not contain | value = "test_"` (starts with `test_`)

Answer (score 1):

> can I run something similar to Field item = tag | operator =  does not contain | value = "test_" (starts with test_)

No, by default we cannot achieve that, in work item query we can only `contain/does not contain` the complete tag just as you did, cannot set the clause starts with `test_`)

However, as a workaround we can achieve that by calling the REST API ([Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1)) in a script, then filter the test cases by tag starts with `test_`).

Below PowerShell script works for me:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection", 
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$user = "domain\user",
   [string]$token = "password"  
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=3.1"

function CreateJsonBody
{
    $value = @"
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State],[System.Tags] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Case' AND [State] <> 'Closed' AND [State] <> 'Removed' order by [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}

"@
 return $value
}
$json = CreateJsonBody

#Get the urls for WIs
$queryresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$wiurls = $queryresult.workItems.url

cls

#Filter the work items which doesn't contain the string "test_" in the tag
$wis = @()

foreach($wiurl in $wiurls){

$wi = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $wiurl -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

if ($wi.fields.'System.Tags' -notlike 'test_*') # Filter the work items which not contains "test_" in tag
    {
        $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WitID" = $wi.id
          "Title" = $wi.fields.'System.Title'
          "AssignedTo" = $wi.fields.'System.AssignedTo'
          "ChangedDate" = $wi.fields.'System.ChangedDate'
          "ChangedBy" = $wi.fields.'System.ChangedBy'
          "WorkItemType" = $wi.fields.'System.WorkItemType'
          "Tags" = $wi.fields.'System.Tags'
          "URL" = $wiurl
        } 

    $wis += $customObject   
    }

}
    $wis | Select-Object `
                WitID,
                Title, 
                AssignedTo,
                ChangedDate, 
                ChangedBy,
                WorkItemType,
                Tags,
                URL #|export-csv -Path D:\filename.csv -NoTypeInformation # remove the # to export the query list to a csv file, then you can open the file with microsoft excel.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I am pretty new to PowerShell. Greatly appreciate if you could print me a link to understand how to write this in PowerShell.